# How do I get lettering.js working with soft hyphens?

Tags: css, webfonts, typography

On applying lettering.js to my headings, the (manually included) soft hyphens are ignored, causing the heading not to hyphenate. More specifically, adding HTML around letters messes up hyphenation. Is there a way around this?